# Full calendar not updating to database

Tags: php, mysql

I've searched and tried just about everything I have come across with no luck.   All of the proper parameters show up in the console log but somehow are not getting passed on to the database.  Hoping someone can shed some light on this.

**update.php**

```
<?php

/* Values received via ajax */
$Job = $_POST['id'];
$date_assigned = $_POST['start'];

// connection to the database
try {
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=service', 'root', 'root');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
    // update the records
    $sql = "UPDATE install SET date_assigned=? WHERE Job=?";
    $q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($date_assigned,$Job));
?>
```

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'update.php',
    data: 'title=' + info.event.title + '&start='+ start + '&id='+ info.event.id ,
    success: function(json) {
        console.log('succes:', info.event.title);
        console.log('start:', start);
        //console.log('Eind tijd:', info.event.end.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' '));
        console.log('ID:', info.event.id);
        console.log('auto:', recourceid);
        calendar.rerenderEvents();
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you post the actual output of $_POST? It could well be the format of the date, Mysql Expects it to be in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` if you are using a DATETIME field.

Comment: Please add an error handling to your code, so you can see where the problems lies

Comment: the console log is outputting  "start: 2019-11-14 12:00:00"

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` what does that output?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be outputting anything.  Does this mean that I am not passing my parameters to my update statement?

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer for me was simple.  There is no password set to my database and I was specifying one in my connection.  Once I removed that it worked as expected.  Thank you for the help.  Sorry for wasting time on something silly that I should have caught.

Comment: There's no need to apologise. I've been a developer for the majority of my life and little things like this, or a missing semi-colon still catch me out from time to time! It's one of the fun parts of development! :)